# Sound comes up after 9 seconds at startup

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, ubuntu-studio

I just built a new computer for my organ simulator (Grandorgue) based on Ubuntu Studio.

Everything works fine and fast, BUT after booting, approx 9 seconds after the appearence of Plasma GUI, a message "soundcard-name analog stereo" is briefly displayed at the center of the screen.

If I launch Grandorgue before the message: no sound (but Midi works). If I launch Grandorgue after the message, I get sound. The phenomenon prevents me to set auto-start for Grandorgue.

I am using Rt/Pulsaudio and Alsa. Jack is stopped.
I tried with the on-mainboard chipset and with the target EMU 0404: same behavior.

The content of the message comes from PulseAudio, because 1/text is one of the labels seen in Studio Controls/Open Pulse Control/Output devices 2/when I change the output device in this menu, the message changes in the same fashion.

It seems that identification of the sound cards takes an abnormally long time, that it hangs somewhere. Have you any idea of the guilty? Is there any log following the audio setup when the machine starts?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu Studio are you using?

Comment: UbuntuStudio 22.04.02
Kernel 6.5.0-low latency (64bits)